# jquery submit causes error due to recursion

Tags: jquery, submit

I have a form with onsumbit attribute. I am calling a javascript function on the onsumbit.
I need to set some values on hidden variables before the form actually submits. That bit is done in the SaveQuery() function. I also have a link on the page which does the same action of submitting the form. I have added the onsubmit, so that the form gets submitted when some one presses the Enter key.

The problem is that when using jquery v1.4.4 library, the form seems to be submitted recursively. How do I avoid that from happening. With jquery v1.3.2, there doesn't seem to be a problem.

The Form:

```
<form id="savequery" action="savedquery.aspx" method="post" onsubmit="SaveQuery(); return false;">
        <input type="hidden" id="orig_q" name="orig_q" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" id="isFullText" name="isFullText" value="" />
        <input id="queryName" name="queryName" value="New Query" />
        </form>
        <table class="centerButton">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div id="proceedSave" class="butActive idProceed">
                            <p>
                            </p>
                            <div>
                                <a href="#" onclick="SaveQuery();">Proceed</a></div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- duplicate text item -->
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

SaveQuery Function:

```
SaveQuery = function () {
    $("#orig_q").val(document.getElementById("txtQuery").value);
    $("#isFullText").val(document.getElementById("chkFulltext").checked);
    $("#savequery").submit();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of stopping the submission and triggering it, you can just let it pass though:

```
onsubmit="SaveQuery();"

var SaveQuery = function () {
  $("#orig_q").val(document.getElementById("txtQuery").value);
  $("#isFullText").val(document.getElementById("chkFulltext").checked);
}
```

Comment: how will this submit the form on click of the link?

Comment: @itsbalur - forms should have submit buttons - there is no valid reason not to in my opinion.

Comment: @itsbalur: It would have to both call the method and submit the form: `onclick="SaveQuery();$("#savequery").submit();"`.

Answer (score 2):

Your calling `SaveQuery` in **both** the `onsubmit` handler for the `<form>`, and the click action for the `<a>`. The function then calls `submit()` again, which will trigger the function, which calls `submit()`, which triggers the function, etc... so of course it recurses! Just call `SaveQuery` on the click event and it should be fine.

Comment: I can't find anything in the jQuery documentation that says that the `submit()` method will specifically trigger the onsubmit event. The built in `submit` method will not trigger the event.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment on the differences between the two libraries, however I would suggest that a simple ammendment to your code would fix the issue.

In your form tag you have an `onsubmit="SaveQuery();` tab, and then you call this function when you click on `Proceed`. In my eyes this ought to present the behavior you see, regardless of whether earlier versions of jQuery mask it.

Simply task this `onsubmit` declaration out.

**Random bonus comment**

You're mixing your JavaScript and jQuery DOM interaction methods. Why not just use jQuery:

```
$("#orig_q").val($("#txtQuery").val());
$("#isFullText").val($("#chkFulltext").attr("checked"));
```

Comment: if the onsumbit declaration is commented out, the form would not submit when the user presses Enter key, right?

Comment: @itsbalur - true, so handling the form submit action is better than handling the click action.